# Find shortest subsequence that contains all numbers within range

Tags: c++, optimization

I am supposed to find the shortest fragment of an int-array that contains all numbers from `a,...,b` where `a` and `b` are integers.

My initial approach was to keep adding the values of the array to a set until the set has the length of the range but starting from that I don't know how I could come up with the shortest sequence?

```
int shortestFragmentSize(std::vector<int> &values, int a, int b) {
    std::unordered_set<int> range;
    const int range_size = (b - a) + 1;
    size_t lidx = 0;
    size_t ridx = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i) {
        if( ranges.size() == range_size ) {
            break;
        }
        const int val = values.at(i);
        if ( val >= a && val <= b ) {
            if( range.find(val) == range.end() ) {
                range.insert(val);
            }
        }
        ridx += 1;
    }
    if( range.size() != range_size )
        return -1;
    return (ridx - lidx);
}
```

In the example `[2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4]` with `a=2` and `b=4` this would choose the first 4 numbers but actually `4, 3, 2` is the shortest subsequence so the result should be 3.

Any tips if my initial ideas can be modified to find the shortest subsequence?

Comment: Think about using a counting map instead of a set.

Comment: *Any tips if my initial ideas can be modified to find the shortest subsequence?* -- Advice -- You should plan with pencil and paper how the problem is solved before writing a single line of code.   I see too many times these "competitive programming questions", where writing code is automatically done without a proper plan.  It makes absolutely no sense and is a waste of time to write up a solution you know will not work with such a simple test case.  What if the "solution" looks absolutely nothing like your attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unordered set is not a bad starting point but I think you have to keep track of all candidate solutions. Something like with:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>


struct CandidateSequence
{
    std::unordered_set<int> contained;
    std::size_t start, end;

    std::size_t length() const noexcept
    { return end - start; }

    CandidateSequence() noexcept
    : start(), end()
    {}
    explicit CandidateSequence(std::size_t start) noexcept
    : start(start), end()
    {}
    bool operator<(const CandidateSequence& o) const noexcept {
        return length() < o.length();
    }
    // return true if value was not already contained
    bool add(int value) {
        return contained.insert(value).second;
    }
    void setFinished(std::size_t end) {
        this->end = end;
    }
};
```

I change the interface slightly,

- for const-correctness on the input vector
- to return the sequence range [start, end) for easier debugging

```cpp
std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>
shortestFragmentSize(const std::vector<int>& values, int a, int b) {
    const std::size_t target_count = static_cast<std::size_t>(b - a + 1);
    CandidateSequence best;
    std::vector<CandidateSequence> candidates;
    using candidate_iterator = std::vector<CandidateSequence>::iterator;
```

Now we iterate over all values. If it is in range, we create a new candidate sequence starting at that index.

```cpp
    for(std::size_t i = 0, n = values.size(); i < n; ++i) {
        int value = values[i];
        if(value < a || value > b)
            continue;
        candidates.emplace_back(i);
```

Now we have to do two things: 1. Try to add the current value to all candidates. 2. Find those sequences that are now complete. I use [`std::partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) for this but you can split this in two loops or reimplement `partition`. It's not hard.

```cpp
        const candidate_iterator completed = std::partition(
                candidates.begin(), candidates.end(),
                [value, i, target_count](CandidateSequence& candidate) {
                    if(! candidate.add(value))
                        return true; // sequence already contained value
                    if(candidate.contained.size() != target_count)
                        return true; // incomplete
                    candidate.setFinished(i + 1);
                    return false;
                });
```

We now save the best completed sequence, if any.

```cpp
        if(completed == candidates.end()) // none complete
            continue;
        // find shortest sequence
        candidate_iterator cur_best =
                std::min_element(completed, candidates.end());
        // if first valid sequence or better than last best, keep it
        if(best.contained.empty() || *cur_best < best)
            best = std::move(*cur_best);
```

Now we clean up. We erase all other completed candidate solutions and also incomplete sequences that are too long. For the second part, we use the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom&oldid=1175133058). Technically, that step is optional.

```cpp
        // discard other solutions
        candidates.erase(completed, candidates.end());
        // discard candidates that have no chance to become the best
        candidates.erase(std::remove_if(
                candidates.begin(), candidates.end(),
                [i, &best](const CandidateSequence& candidate) {
                    return i - candidate.start + 1 >= best.length();
                }), candidates.end());
```

That's all for the loop. We can now return the best solution, if any.

```cpp
    }
    return std::make_pair(best.start, best.end);
}
```

Some test code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> values {{2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4}};
    int a = 2, b = 4;
    std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t> shortest = shortestFragmentSize(values, a, b);
    std::cout << shortest.first << ' ' << shortest.second << '\n';
    for(std::size_t i = shortest.first; i < shortest.second; ++i)
        std::cout << values[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
2 5
4 3 2
```

Best case, this runs in O(n). Worst case would be an input sequence such as `{2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, ...}` without any 4. This would create a new subsequence in every iteration and since none ever completes, it runs in O(n^2). I'm sure there are smart ways of removing redundant candidates.

This whole problem seems closely related to regular expressions. Finding the subsequence is similar to a regular expression like

```
  (2 .* (3 .* 4)|(4 .* 3))
| (3 .* (2 .* 4)|(4 .* 2))
| (4 .* (2 .* 3)|(3 .* 4))
```

So it should be possible to solve it with [the same strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Regular_expression&oldid=1174727609#Implementations_and_running_times)

Another optimization would be switching out the `unordered_set` for a [`boost::dynamic_bitset`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) with the lowest bit representing value `a`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! Do you think this could be solved with dynamic programming?